# Python Dictionary with Variable Array keys

Tags: python

```
self.PARSE_TABLE={"$_ERROR":self.WEEK_ERRORS,"$_INFORM":self.WEEK_INFORM,"$_REDIR":self.WEEK_REDIRECTS,"$_SERVER_ERROR":self.WEEK_SERVER_ERROR,"$_BYTES":self.WEEK_BYTES,"$_HITS":self.WEEK_HITS}


for j in self.PARSE_TABLE:
            print j
            break
```

When I run this on my python the first element I get is S_REDIR can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries don't maintain order. The order you get from iterating over them may not be the order in which you inserted the elements. This is the price you pay for near-instant lookup of values by key. In short, the behavior you are seeing is correct and expected, and may even vary from run to run of the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

It normal behaviour. Inside dictionary and set using [hash codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). If you want orderd keys use `self.PARSE_TABLE.keys.sort()`. Also you can use OrderedDict from [collection library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary by default stores all the keys in its own convenient order rather to the order we gave.

If the order of the keys should be maintained, you can use OrderedDict which came to implementation from the python version 3.0

P.S. I don't think sorting keys would do any help in preserving the order given.

Comment: cpython2.7 also has `OrderedDict`.